# Unable to use generate models with jodatime using Swagger-codegen maven plugin for jersey2

Tags: java, maven, jodatime, jersey-2.0, swagger-codegen

Using the following configuration for the maven swagger-codegen plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <ignoreFileOverride>${basedir}/.swagger-codegen-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                        <language>jaxrs</language>
                        <library>jersey2</library>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                            <apiPackage>com.github.jmccloskey.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.github.jmccloskey.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.github.jmccloskey.invoker</invokerPackage>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The code generation works, but uses Java Date in the models that are generated. From the swagger-codegen documentation this can be overridden to use JodaTime by adding the following inside the configOptions:

```
<dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
```

This is what I am trying to do, but I get a compilation failure:

```
.../JodaDateTimeProvider.java:[3,41] package com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component does not exist
```

I think spi is what Jersey1 uses for dependency injection, whereas Jersey2 uses hk2.

I was able to resolve the compilation failure by adding jersey-bundle to my dependencies (along with a bunch of others such as jettison, rome and javax.mail) but had runtime issues in my API:

```
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: method inject on com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory
```

Mixing in Jersey 1 dependencies is not the right approach.
Is there a way to configure the swagger-codegen maven plugin to use hk2 instead?

For a full sample project see this [github repo](https://github.com/j-mccloskey/swagger-java-api). Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.